# What's the right element name for fill_in a collection field in capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

Here is the html source code for mfg_process_id field on quote form. This field is fed with a collection of the processes.

```
<div class="input select required quote_mfg_process_id">
<label class="select required control-label" for="quote_mfg_process_id">
<abbr title="required">*</abbr>
<span class="translation_missing" title="translation missing: en.Mfg Process">Mfg Process</span>
</label>
<select id="quote_mfg_process_id" class="select required" name="quote[mfg_process_id]">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="1">Process 1</option>
<option value="2">Process 2</option>
</select>
</div>
```

There is an error for this field with code `fill_in 'quote_mfg_process_id', :with => mfg.id` (mfg is a process instance):

```
Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find field "quote_mfg_process_id"
```

The error are similar when trying with the followings:

```
fill_in 'quote[mfg_process_id]', :with => mfg.id
fill_in 'Mfg Process', :with => mfg.name
```

There is no error however, for text fields on the same page. We figured that the error must be caused by the collection fed to the field (same error for another collection field). According to capybara fill_in fills in fields and just pass the label text or the name of the input. But it seems not the case for a collection field. What's the right name for a collection field in capybara?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capybara's [`fill_in`](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Actions#fill_in-instance_method) is for **text** based fields. You want to use [`select`](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Actions#select-instance_method) for select options.

Comment: select(mfg.name, :from => 'quote_mfg_process_id'). Thanks.